# Open a Website in the Background and access its fields in a flutter app

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app, I want to read and write from text fields on a specific website. The website I am talking about has no backend and execudes javascript code in the browser when you enter values in its calculation fields. I want to read/write values from my app into those text fields. Is it possible to achieve this using a webview?
Is this possible at all?
If possible, I would like to not pull the user out of my apps ui.
Implementing the calculation tool for myself would use a ton of time.

Comment: You want to do injection of code? Google Play will not allow your app to be published if you read/write to a website without the user knowing it since you could teoretically make a keylogger and steal user data. You might be better using a invisible webview. Or even better porting the library to dart , it should not be that difficult to port math calculations to dart

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get started. This uses a locally hosted file as a webview, but no reason you couldn't adapt this to a public website.

```
RaisedButton(
onPressed: () {
                  showAboutDialog(
                      context: context,
                      children: [
                        Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                          Text("Please don't sue me"),
                          Container(
                            height: 160,
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Container(
                                height: 180,
                                child: WebView(
                                  initialUrl: "",
                                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                                  // this is defined elsewhere and fixes a (at one time) bug with gesture detection
                                  gestureRecognizers: [
                                    Factory(() =>
                                        PlatformViewVerticalGestureRecognizer()),
                                  ].toSet(),                                  
                                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController
                                      webViewController) async {
                                    _controller = webViewController;
                                    await loadHtmlFromAssets(
                                        'public/index.html', _controller);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ],
                      applicationVersion: "Version 0.1",
                      applicationName: "Your Application",
                      applicationLegalese: "",
                      applicationIcon:
                          ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/images/pos_icon.png")));
                },
                child: Text("About, and Legalese for masochists"),
),
```

Comment: If I read this correctly, it would open a dialog where the page would be shown from a locally stored index.html file, right?

Comment: @Salatgurke, yep that's right. So, not exactly what you're after but a potential alternative/starting point depending on what exactly you're after